# Best of Code Review 2015

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

As 2015 comes to an end, let's kick off Best of Code Review 2015!

All Code Review users will be invited to nominate (link to) the best questions and answers from this year, and showcase them as examples of what great CR questions and answers should look like.  Prizes in the form of bounties will be awarded wherever feasible.

---

### Conclusion

The winners of Best of Code Review 2015 are:

- **Best Newcomer Answer (best answer by a user who had not posted an answer before 2015):**

  - @5gon12eder on [Easier user input in C++](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/107067), with 7 meta votes
- **Night and Day (most dramatic improvement):**

  - @MatthiasEttinger on @MarieAnne's [IP and router connections](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108781), with 7 meta votes
- **Lots of Laughs (answer that makes the best use of humor to illustrate a point):**

  - @Vogel612 on [LOL'ing-Up Project Euler One](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79306), with 8 meta votes
- **Diplomat (tough advice in an answer, delivered in the most tactful manner):**

  - @Barry on [Connect 4 refine the diagonal check](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/115336), with 7 meta votes
- **Exterminator (answer that points out the most obscure bug):**

  - @Quuxplusone on [Hybrid Lock Implementation (C++)](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/95021), with 12 meta votes

Bounty prizes will be awarded shortly by the generous prize sponsors.

I hope that Best of Code Review 2015 has helped to showcase contributions from our members — not just the winners, but the other nominees as well.  Let's do this again next year!

Comment: I am willing to supply +500 bounty for each  winning ***answer***  in the 3-top categories that reward answers (i.e. I cannot reward "best ABC question" with a bounty).

Comment: Why not count downvotes? It would make it easier to track the standings for everyone, including users who don't have enough rep to see up-down vote count details

Comment: @janos Allowing downvotes would essentially give everyone two votes. One vote per person is simpler. I'm counting on members to be on good behaviour and refrain from downvoting. (However, if a downvote occurs, I'll note that in the final tally.) In any case, you shouldn't let other users' votes influence your own choices.

Comment: @rolfl + 200_success: Are selfie answers eligible for your bounties?

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely - as far as I am concerned, yes.

Comment: I am also willing to chip in for the bounty rewards. Maybe we can split evenly. Let's coordinate when the time comes.

Comment: @rolfl: Good Idea. I am willing to donate +500 as well (for each winning answer in the 3-top categories). Maybe we can get a pool going and then distribute the points in some way.

Comment: How about a booby prize (or is that too mean and micro aggressive for this generation).

Comment: @LokiAstari Booby prize — meaning for the worst? There is too much crap to make that workable, and besides, it would attract downvotes. Second-place prizes, maybe.

Comment: @200_success: Booby => funny https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=booby+prize  going by Janos recent post: answer a question that is obviously going to be closed.

Comment: @LokiAstari We already have a category for funny.

Comment: @200_success: Not the same.

Comment: Just a question, can you nominate your own post?

Comment: @TheCoffeeCup Yes, you may nominate your own post.

Answer (score 24):

[**Best Newcomer (Answer) category:**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6399/23788) Best answer by a user who had not posted an answer before 2015.

Answer (score 18):

[**Lots of Laughs:**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6401/23788) Answer that makes the best use of humor to illustrate a point.

Comment: If this isn't retained, then we clearly hate fun.

Answer (score 18):

[**Night and Day:**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6400/23788) The most dramatic improvement (nominate both the question with the most hopeless code and the answer that cleans it up the best)

Answer (score 16):

[**Diplomat:**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6403/23788) Tough advice in an answer, delivered in the most tactful manner

Answer (score 16):

[**Exterminator:**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6402/23788) Answer that points out the most interesting obscure bug in the original code.

Answer (score 15):

**Best shortening**

Of course I am not talking about CodeGolf, this category aims to reward answers that given an absurdly long and bloated code in the question, shorten it significantly while retaining functionality **and improving readibility** at the same time.

Comment: Wouldn't that overlap with *Night & Day*?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Not really, Night & Day is for _bad_ code, be it short or bloated, this one focuses on the bloated code.

Answer (score 14):

**Best Title category:** The question with the best title. (If the title was later added by someone else, be sure to credit the user who edited the title.)

Comment: [Shamelessly stolen from 2014](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3868/52915) where it was a success.

Comment: My concern is that questions with good titles don't go unnoticed, and as such most probably have already been very well rewarded, by going hot and getting tons upvotes. An extra reward on top would be like making the rich richer. But maybe it's just me. (I'm pretty sure this category will get selected again.)

Comment: @janos "showcase them as examples of what great CR questions and answers should look like". Having a great title helps with being a great question. Regardless of whether the question has been rewarded already it should definitely be a category because it's an important part of asking a question.

Comment: it doesn't have to be rewarded with reputation.

Answer (score 12):

**Not As Easy As It Looks category:** Question that superficially appears simple but turns out to be more difficult than expected

Answer (score 10):

**Best Newcomer (Question) category:** Best question by a user who had not posted a question before 2015.

Answer (score 3):

A little late as the voting is already started.

**Best welcoming comment**: New users can be overwhelmed by our community, but sometimes a good welcome to the community can also grab their attention to come back in later stages, as they can see our mentality is not the same as SO.

Answer (score 0):

**Best self-answer category**: For questions that the OP then answered later.