# Best of Code Review 2015 - Best Newcomer (answer) category

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2015 - Best Newcomer (answer)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6384/23788) category.

> *Best answer by a user who had not posted an answer before 2015.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the nominated answer. Include a short explanation of what makes the suggestions in the answer exceptional.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post, nominated answers must have a creation date in 2015, downvotes don't count, and Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

Nominating this answer to [Easier user input in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/107067/84718)

There is more topics covered in the answer than lines of code in the question. All thoroughly developed, educational, and to the point. What more?

Comment: (An answer as long as the one linked would profit from a (media)wiki style ToC)

Comment: I love that answer so much.

Comment: Thank you, I value this appreciation a lot. This is an especially nice welcome to a site that is already very friendly in general. 2015, while the first, won't be the last year I've participated in Code Review.