# Best of Code Review 2015 - Night and Day category

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2015 - Night and Day](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6383/23788) category.

> *The most dramatic improvement (nominate both the question with the most hopeless code and the answer that cleans it up the best).*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the nominated answer. Include a short explanation of what makes the suggestions in the answer exceptional.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post, nominated answers must have a creation date in 2015, downvotes don't count, and Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee pair a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Nominating [Shorter cleaner technique of writing code with variables and lists?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/108691/84718) for the "night" and [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108781/84718) for the "day". More because the night was so dark than the day is bright.

The code went from extremely long, almost all-in-one, function involving tons of copypasta and similarly purposed `nameX` variables to OOP approach involving a list of objects parsing their attributes. Reducing the length of the code by 83% while largely increasing readability.

Comment: +*`copypasta`*+

Answer (score 4):

Nominating myself: the "Night" was a weird busy loop involving the current time and an atomic long, as well as a vague specification.  "Day" is atomically incrementing a long.

[Generating a 64 bit unique integer in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79818/generating-a-64-bit-unique-integer-in-java/80064#80064)

Answer (score 3):

Question: [Find the Nth number divisible by only 2, 3, 5, or 7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/110647/31292)

Deceptive problem, where OP fell into the easy trap of thinking his solution was \$O(n)\$ simply because he was doing a constant number of operations per iteration. Additionally the code was mixing many responsibilities and could needed some love.

[My answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/110681/31292) provides both a cleaner way to solve the problem using his algorithm, but more importantly goes through and describes why his solution wasn't actually \$O(n)\$ and was actually exponential (with tables!) and then provides an actual \$O(n)\$ solution, complete with timing differences.

Exponential time to Linear time seems like night and day to me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm personally against nominating mine own question/answer.
After some thinking on what a good candidate could be I remembered this one :

Question : [Creating a numeric phone keypad](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104879/creating-a-numeric-phone-keypad)

It's a very simple program to set text to digits on the phone.

[The answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104879/creating-a-numeric-phone-keypad/104882#104882) is just not only a code review but also inspect on performance.
There was a whole discussion about this one in the chat.
With working together in the chat we got to this great answer with a lot of benchmarks, where we can see on how simple things already could improve our performance.

While I'm only a small part of the solution, I'm not the only one who took part of this.
This answer also helped me succeeding a technical test for new work and it will always remember me that a team effort can create awsome code/answers.

Answer (score 1):

@coderodde's project was posted as two questions: [Discrete event simulation of a prioritized lunch queue in Java (Data structures)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113604/discrete-event-simulation-of-a-prioritized-lunch-queue-in-java-data-structures) and [Discrete event simulation of a prioritized lunch queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113607/discrete-event-simulation-of-a-prioritized-lunch-queue/114823#114823).

On the surface, it looked like very nice code:

> ```
> Population population = 
>         RandomPopulationGenerator 
>         .withRandom(random)
>         .with(15).peopleWithDegree(AcademicDegree.DOCTOR)
>         .with(40).peopleWithDegree(AcademicDegree.MASTER)
>         .with(100).peopleWithDegree(AcademicDegree.BACHELOR)
>         .with(250).peopleWithDegree(AcademicDegree.UNDERGRADUATE)
>         .withMeanLunchTime(10800.0)
>         .withLunchTimeStandardDeviation(1200.0);
> ```

However, [my answer](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/114823/9357) pointed out that this cool-looking fluent interface had significant disadvantages.  Moreover,

- literal modelling of the problem hindered code reuse and understanding
- statistics gathering was cumbersome
- non-chronological progression of time necessitated a time-travel hack
- it wasn't obvious that the simulation would terminate cleanly

An event-driven complete rewrite addressed those issues, and also reduced the code from ~1200 lines to ~400 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Question: [A little integer parser vs clean code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/a-little-integer-parser-vs-clean-code)

Not hopeless per-se, just a verbose solution to a simple problem from a beginner (we all have to start somewhere, don't we?).

[(My) answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/a-little-integer-parser-vs-clean-code/88856#88856) attempts to explain:

- Why the problem is simple enough to warrant a simple answer,
- How learning APIs is valuable for beginners,
- an alternative solution,
- and also provided additional advice if 'reinventing-the-wheel' in the question is a form of academic exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Question: [Sonar remarks make SQL unreadable?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83174/sonar-remarks-make-sql-unreadable)

This started off as a question about concatenating literal strings and how that can be improved to 'pass' Sonar.

[(My) answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83174/sonar-remarks-make-sql-unreadable/83212#83212) introduced a builder-like approach to the query construction, which is [well-received](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83174/sonar-remarks-make-sql-unreadable/83212#comment149713_83212) by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Question: [Writing a program to read a maximum of 99 elements in an iteration from a list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94883/writing-a-program-to-read-a-maximum-of-99-elements-in-an-iteration-from-a-list)

Relatively simple problem, but the code had major problems with comments and hard-coding.

[(My) answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94883/writing-a-program-to-read-a-maximum-of-99-elements-in-an-iteration-from-a-list/94912#94912) started by focusing on the comments, and then concluded with an alternative solution based nothing more than Java's built-in methods.