# Best of Code Review 2015 - Lots of Laughs category

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for the [Best of Code Review 2015 - Lots of Laughs](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6381/23788) category.

> *Answer that makes the best use of humor to illustrate a point.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the nominated answer, as well as a short explanation of what makes that post worthy of being nominated in this category, and why it should win over the others.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post, nominated answers must have a creation date in 2015, downvotes don't count, and Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

When I saw this, the first thing which came to mind were CR's couple questions under the [lolcode](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lolcode) tag.

Therefore I nominate Vogel612's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79306/35559) to [LOL'ing-Up Project Euler One](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79298/loling-up-project-euler-one). A question using a language which is simply ridiculous calls for an equally humorous answer, and I think this covers it well!

A very good review as a matter of fact!

Comment: I actually find my other lolcode answer a funnier review, but I ain't complaining :D

Comment: @Vogel612 me as well but it wasn't from 2015!

Answer (score 1):

Because I really started laughing while I read **braceophilia** I would like to nominate [holroy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/78136/holroy)'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108325/29371) to [Checking if text is not displayed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108321/checking-if-text-is-not-displayed)