# Best of Code Review 2015 - Diplomat category

Tags: discussion, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for [Best of Code Review 2015 — Diplomat category](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6380/23788):

> *Tough advice in an answer, delivered in the most tactful manner.*

In your nomination post, please make sure to include a link to the nominated answer, as well as a short explanation of what makes that post worthy of being nominated in this category, and why it should win over the others.

---

<sub>**Small characters at the bottom:**
Only one nomination per post, nominated answers must have a creation date in 2015, downvotes don't count, and Santa reserves the right to award the top-voted nominee a special bounty as a token of appreciation on behalf of the Code Review community.</sub>

Comment: What's considered *tough advice*?

Comment: I'd recognise _Your stated conviction leads to harm. Act on it no more. Change it, or fail._

Answer (score 6):

I'm a bit hesitant to post my answer to [Connect 4 refine the diagonal check](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/115336/31292), mainly since I guess OP didn't really accept the tough advice.

I usually try very hard to understand all the code in OP, regardless of how poorly or cryptically written, but this was one of the few questions in which I gave up because I had no idea what was going on anywhere. Tact has never been my strong suit, but I tried very hard to convey the importance of readability.

---

The existence of this category and the desire for self-improvement on the tact front led me to completely rewrite my answer to [C++ concurrency library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/115357/31292). The OP again was completely unreceptive to any advice, culminating in the amazing comment of

> My choice of naming is excellent. This is C++ standard committee whose choice was poor.

so I'm answering that question less for his sake than for future readers of the question.

Comment: I, too, hesitated to nominate your answer to "connect 4". Somehow having spent so much time deciphering what was going on and reading the OP disregarding your answer as being _not what they were asking for_ had me wonder if this truly was a good nomination here. But I forgot that answers are _less for his sake than for future readers of the question_. +1

Answer (score 1):

I'll nominate [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106307/printing-out-a-diamond-with-a-user-inputted-size/106314#106314) of mine to code in C++.  The question contained this line:

> since I am the only one reading my code, readability doesn't matter to me

Naturally, that got jumped on by pretty much everyone viewing the question, but in the answer I tried to not only gently convey why readability is important, but then went on to show a version of the code half the size of the original, but with much improved readability, demonstrating one doesn't need to sacrifice readability to write compact code.

Comment: (`jumped on by pretty much everyone` - with [200-success](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357)'s comment not short on diplomacy) While I'm taken to the calm (staid?) tone, I fail the see the `Tough advice` part.